# Difference between Enterprise Continuum, the Architecture Repository, and the Architecture Content framework

Tags: terminology, togaf

Could anyone explain to me the difference between Enterprise Continuum, the Architecture Repository, and the Architecture Content Framework according to TOGAF framework?

Answer (score 6):

The **Architecture Content Framework** (with the **Content Metamodel**) informs on what content to produce at what phase of the **ADM** cycle, and also gives a model to structure those Architecture Deliverables. The produced content fall into three categories: **Deliverables**, **Artifacts** and **Building Blocks**.

> The content framework should therefore be used as a companion to the
>   ADM. The ADM describes what needs to be done to create an architecture
>   and the content framework describes what the architecture should look
>   like once it is done.

Documentation (existing and produces one) is expected to be stored in a repository -- the **Enterprise Repository** – which is divided into three parts; the **Requirement Repository**, the **Architecture Repository**, the **Solutions Repository**.

The content produced during the **ADM** cycle is mainly to be stored in the **Architecture Repository**.

The **Enterprise Continuum** is the classification method for organizing architecture and solution artifacts, both internal and external to the **Architecture Repository**. It can be considered as a virtual repository containing the **Architecture Repository** amongst other things.

A good explanation with the relations to the ADM cycle can be found here: [grahamberrisford.com](http://grahamberrisford.com/AM%20TOGAF/AM%20TOGAF%205%20Enterprise%20Continuum.htm)

Answer (score 4):

If you like to understand it as a layman, Here are my explanation:

Continuum means, "continuous changing at a slow pace". Enterprise continuum means slowly changing enterprises. It's merely a term to prepare the context.

Architecture Repository is like a library where we keep all our books/documents/contents. It has all available or newly created/modified contents related to architecture. It is newly introduced in Togaf 9

Like Architecture Repository, Architecture Content Framework is newly introduced in Togaf 9. It's an improved version of input/output of Togaf 8.1.1. It provides more concrete realization reference for outputs of different phases of ADM.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine that there is a bookcase where the shelfs are built following a specific layout. The bookcase is filled with books that are arranged with a classification rule. Each book is written in a consistent style:

- Architecture Content Framework: How a book is composed. For example any book in this bookcase should contain a Table of Contents, the body text, Index, etc.
- Architecture Repository: The bookcase with shelfs follows a specific layout.
- Enterprise Continuum: The classification rule.